# Keep-Alive is active, where is the close coming from?

Tags: apache-2.2, connection

Apache server
SuPHP (php as CGI?)

When I look through phpinfo, I see Keep-Alive as being active/on.
When I use tools like RedBot, I see Connection: Close

If I set Headers (via htaccess or php) as
Connection: Keep-Alive
the response I see is
Connection: Keep-Alive, close

I've scanned through all my php files - nothing seems to be setting the Connection: to "close".

So where is it coming from,
and how do I remove it,
or replace it with Keep-Alive?

I've tried to unset via htaccess.
I've tried to set empty header via php.
Neither method has worked.
(Yes, I've read it's a config thing - but it is "on" ... so why am I seeing "close" ???)

Comment: What's the client sending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache won't keepalive for a CGI request - although it's technically possible to do this, it doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Do you really need suPHP? CGI performance sucks big time.

Comment: No choice, as that's what the host runs as on the shared platform.